# Sum with Groupby

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to find due of all row with a groupby

For that i have used following Query.

```
$due = DB::table('transactions')
      ->join('customers','transactions.customer_id','customers.id')
      ->whereYear('transactions.updated_at', '=', date('Y')) 
      ->where('customers.status','=',0) 
      ->groupBy('transactions.customer_id')
      ->sum('due');
```

But the result returns only first row. But if i used following query it returns exact result.

```
  $query3 = DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('customers','transactions.customer_id','customers.id')
        ->whereYear('transactions.updated_at', '=', date('Y')) 
        ->where('customers.status','=',0) 
        ->groupBy('transactions.customer_id')->get();

    $due = $query3->sum('due');
```

Why is that why can't we get sum with `groupby`?

Comment: remove `groupBy` and then `sum` will work.

Comment: try this     $query3 = DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('customers','transactions.customer_id','customers.id')
        ->select(DB::raw("sum(due)as duep"),*)
        ->whereYear('transactions.updated_at', '=', date('Y')) 
        ->where('customers.status','=',0) 
        ->groupBy('transactions.customer_id')->get();

Comment: @GauravGupta, this will work I think. It should be answer

Comment: okay @NikleshRaut i'll put in answer

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$query3 = DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('customers','transactions.customer_id','customers.id')
        ->select(DB::raw("sum(due)as new_col ,column1 ,column3 ,column3"))
        ->whereYear('transactions.updated_at', '=', date('Y')) 
        ->where('customers.status','=',0) 
        ->groupBy('transactions.customer_id')->get();`
```

hope this will work

Comment: I got the following Error:
`Property [new_col] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: TRY THIS   ->select(DB::raw("sum(due)as new_col,*"))

Comment: that throws following error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* from `transactions` inner join `customers` on `transactions`.`customer_id` = `' at line 1 (SQL: select sum(due) as new_col,* from `transactions` inner join `customers` on `transactions`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` where year(`transactions`.`updated_at`) = 2019 and `customers`.`status` = 0 group by `transactions`.`customer_id`)`

Comment: remove * you have type all the column that you need from this table then it will work